# Invertible transformations and invariant vector spaces

Tags: linear-transformations, inverse

Let T be an invertible linear operator on a vector space V . Let U
be an invariant vector subspace of V with respect to T. Prove that U is also invariant with respect to
T^-1

So, I understand what the first line is saying - that its invertible, so here exists an inverse ie T^-1. In fact, i understand the question, and the answer seems relatively intuitive. Im having problems with formulating a formal proof though. Should I start from the definition of T being invertible?

Since it seems intuitive to me, any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: You would probably need to assume $U$ is finite-dimensional.  Otherwise, here's a counterexample: let $V$ be the vector space of functions $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$, $T$ be the right-shift function which sends $(\ldots, x_{-2}, x_{-1}, x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ to $(\ldots, x_{-3}, x_{-2}, x_{-1}, x_0, x_1, \ldots)$, and $U$ be the subspace of sequences such that $x_n = 0$ for $n < 0$.  Then $U$ is invariant under $T$, but not under its inverse which is the left-shift function.

Comment: I’d suggest starting with the definition of a $T$-invariant space.